# Getting access to scoped objects

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function zz(){
var location = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    fullName : function() {
       return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};
return this;
}

var abc= zz();
console.log(abc);  //This works, but it is the the window objects location, I want the  location I have defined
console.log(some code here to print out John);
console.log(some code here to print out Doe);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I choose location as the object name to learn about more about scope collision.

But now I can't figure out how to get to the variables I have defined. I know I have an object named location wrapped in a function zz

I know the object location has a firstName property of John
I know also the object location has a method fullName that will return the John Doe back to the calling reference.

So what do I need to do to output for example John to the console?

Thanks,

Comment: `return location;` ? After the function was run - the `location` object is not reachable anymore (since there are no active references to it)

Comment: ^ that! `this` inside the function when called like that would be the window, that's why `window` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: Rather than use `var`, assign properties to `this`. And since it looks like you are trying to make an object constructor, try using the [`new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) keyword.

```
        function zz() {
            this.location = {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe",
                id: 5566,
                fullName: function () {
                    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
                }
            };

            this.getFirstName = function () {
                return this.location.firstName;
            };

            this.getLastName = function () {
                return this.location.lastName;
            };

        }

        var abc = new zz();
        console.log(abc);  // zz { location={...},  getFirstName=function(),  getLastName=function()}
        console.log(abc.getFirstName(), abc.location.firstName); //John, John
        console.log(abc.getLastName(), abc.location.lastName); //Doe, Doe
        console.log(abc.location.fullName()); //John Doe
```

Comment: Okay chiliNut that is just what I was looking for. Obviously I was missing the new() which I did not know at the time. I appreciate your answer and insight on this!

Answer (score 1):

`var`s are only available within the scope which they are defined with the keyword `var`. I'm pretty sure that you actually want `this` inside your `location` Object to refer to your `location` Object, while you may want more methods in `zz`. Here is how that can be achieved:

```
function zzLoc(context){
  this.firstName = 'John';
  this.lastName = 'Doe';
  this.id = 5566;
  this.fullName = function(){
    return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
  }
  this.parent = context;
}
function zz(){
  this.location = function(){
    return new zzLoc(this);
  }
  // more methods here
}
var wellNow = new zz, loc = wellNow.location();
console.log(loc.fullName());
```

Comment: PHPGlue thanks for your answer as well! I plan on studying both yours and chiliNUT's  to understand the similarities and differences.